# What Internet Explorer settings could cause IE7/IE8 to not load css?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

We have received isolated reports of IE7 & IE8 not loading/parsing the css from our website built on asp.net 4 and hosted on iis 6.  One user recently sent us screen shots to confirm the problem.

- They tried upgrading from IE7 to IE8 which did not fix the problem.
- Firefox installed on the same computer would load the website/css normally
- After investigating we found that resetting their Internet Explorer's settings fixed the problem (Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Reset).  He is now unable to reproduce the problem

We've tried to reproduce the problem with the advanced internet explorer settings on our computers without success.  Any idea what setting could have caused this problem?  Any experience with similar issues?  Thanks!

Comment: Strange, I can't see anything immediately obvious either. Possibly some accessibility settings, developer toolbar, or 3rd party plugin?

Comment: Have you verified that you're sending the right mime type for your css files?

Comment: Hello jeffamaphone - As far as I can tell all the css headers are coming down as text/css per chrome's developer tools.  Here is the site (front page exhibits the behavior): www.icma.org

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar problems with various versions of IE due to malicious or poorly coded add-ons.  Next time you see this you should try having them run IE without add-ons to see if the problem still exists.

Comment: That's a good thought.  I've reached out to the customer to see if they can reproduce the problem and asked them to try running IE without addons.  Thanks for the help!